# Programmatically create a UIView with color gradient with blur effect in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cagradientlayer

I am tying to create a UIview with color gradient and blur effect(360 Degree) using objective c.

[image: Like following]

[image: Rectangle effect]

I can did this gradient effect only one direction. I need the output like rectangle one with 360 degree.

Here is my code

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];

gradient.frame = view.bounds;
gradient.colors = @[(id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor, (id)[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];

[view.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply gradient layer like your code and than after add below code than look it.

```
   if (!UIAccessibilityIsReduceTransparencyEnabled()) {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIBlurEffect *blurEffect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:blurEffect];
//always fill the view
blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds;
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

[self.view addSubview:blurEffectView]; //if you have more UIViews, use an insertSubview API to place it where needed
} else {
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

i hope it will work.